# Jcrop saves previous image

Tags: jquery, jcrop

I have a preview that I am cropping, and a thumbnail that displays the part being cropped. Whenever I choose an new image, the preview does not get updated, instead it keeps the image being used previously. However, the thumbnail does get updated, since it shows the new image. Here is my code...

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#previewSub2').attr('src', e.target.result);
            $('#previewSub').attr('src', e.target.result);
            ...
            var imgwidth = $("#previewSub2").width();
            var imgheight = $("#previewSub2").height();
            $("#previewSub").Jcrop({
                onChange: showPreview,
                onSelect: showPreview,
                aspectRatio: 1,        
                setSelect: [0,imgwidth,0,0],
                minSize: [90,90],
                addClass: 'jcrop-light' 
             });
             ...
```

`previewSub2` is the thumbnail and `previewSub` is the JCrop image I am trying to update. For some reason the following code is not updating it:

```
 $('#previewSub').attr('src', e.target.result);
```

Here is the rest of my code for `showPreview`:

```
function showPreview(coords)
{
var imgSize = $("#previewSub").height();
var imgWidth =  $("#previewSub").width();

var rx = 150 / coords.w;
var ry = 150 / coords.h;

$('#x').val();
$('#y').val();
$('#w').val();
$('#h').val();

$('#previewSub2').css({
    width: Math.round(rx * imgWidth) + 'px',
    height: Math.round(ry * imgSize) + 'px',
    marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * coords.x) + 'px',
    marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * coords.y) + 'px'
});
}
```

Can someone explain to me what I need to do to update `previewSub`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reload the jcrop component like this

```
var jcrop_api = null;
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
       var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        if( jcrop_api ) {
             jcrop_api.destroy();
        }

        $('#previewSub2').attr('src', e.target.result);
        $('#previewSub').attr('src', e.target.result);
        ...
        var imgwidth = $("#previewSub2").width();
        var imgheight = $("#previewSub2").height();

        jcrop_api = $("#previewSub").Jcrop({
            onChange: showPreview,
            onSelect: showPreview,
            aspectRatio: 1,        
            setSelect: [0,imgwidth,0,0],
            minSize: [90,90],
            addClass: 'jcrop-light' 
         });
```

UPDATE: If you're using the latest version of jcrop you should set the api as such:

```
$("#previewSub").Jcrop({
    onChange: showPreview,
    onSelect: showPreview,
    aspectRatio: 1,        
    setSelect: [0,imgwidth,0,0],
    minSize: [90,90],
    addClass: 'jcrop-light' 
    }, function() {
        jcrop_api = this;
});
```

Comment: This seems good, but it doesn't work. After the destroying it, `preview` still does not get updated. In fact, its not showing at all.

Comment: It might be important to note that I hide the image after I choose one the first time. Then, on the second time I show the image again using `show()` in the function above right before `jcrop_api = $('previewSub)...`

Comment: @Bolboa - I added a different approach for setting the api into a variable, please check it